# Couldn't install R packages on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: r, ubuntu

I have installed R into my VM (Ubuntu 14.04) according to this page,

http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/server/install-opensource

and I have also installed `shiny` from R console like the follow.

```
# R

R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10) -- "Spring Dance"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

> install.packages('shiny', verbose = TRUE)
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
system (cmd0): /usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL
also installing the dependencies ‘Rcpp’, ‘bitops’, ‘httpuv’, ‘caTools’, ‘RJSONIO’, ‘xtable’, ‘digest’

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 2003515 bytes (1.9 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.9 Mb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 8734 bytes
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 8734 bytes

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/httpuv_1.3.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 423739 bytes (413 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 413 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/caTools_1.17.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 63326 bytes (61 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 61 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/RJSONIO_1.2-0.2.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1180440 bytes (1.1 Mb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 Mb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/xtable_1.7-3.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 357303 bytes (348 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 348 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/digest_0.6.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 79309 bytes (77 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 77 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.md.tsukuba.ac.jp/src/contrib/shiny_0.9.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 958658 bytes (936 Kb)
opened URL
==================================================
downloaded 936 Kb

foundpkgs: Rcpp, bitops, httpuv, caTools, RJSONIO, xtable, digest, shiny, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/httpuv_1.3.0.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/caTools_1.17.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/RJSONIO_1.2-0.2.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/xtable_1.7-3.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/digest_0.6.4.tar.gz, /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/shiny_0.9.1.tar.gz
files: /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/httpuv_1.3.0.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/caTools_1.17.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/RJSONIO_1.2-0.2.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/xtable_1.7-3.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/digest_0.6.4.tar.gz,
        /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/shiny_0.9.1.tar.gz
1): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/Rcpp_0.11.1.tar.gz'
2): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/bitops_1.0-6.tar.gz'
3): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/RJSONIO_1.2-0.2.tar.gz'
4): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/xtable_1.7-3.tar.gz'
5): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/digest_0.6.4.tar.gz'
6): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/httpuv_1.3.0.tar.gz'
7): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/caTools_1.17.tar.gz'
8): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library' /tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages/shiny_0.9.1.tar.gz'

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages’
```

According to advices (see comments from jdharrison and scottkosty),
I have got output with `debug(install.packages)`.

The follow is last dozens of lines (I omitted appropriately).

```
> debug(install.packages)
> install.packages("shiny")

(snip because of very long outputs)

Browse[2]>
debug: if (status > 0L) warning(gettextf("installation of package %s had non-zero exit status",
    sQuote(update[i, 1L])), domain = NA) else if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: outfile <- if (keep_outputs) {
    paste0(update[i, 1L], ".out")
} else output
Browse[2]>
debug: output
Browse[2]>
debug: args <- c(args0, get_install_opts(update[i, 3L]), "-l", shQuote(update[i,
    2L]), getConfigureArgs(update[i, 3L]), getConfigureVars(update[i,
    3L]), update[i, 3L])
Browse[2]>
debug: status <- system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile)
Browse[2]>
debug: if (!quiet && keep_outputs) writeLines(readLines(outfile))
Browse[2]>
debug: if (status > 0L) warning(gettextf("installation of package %s had non-zero exit status",
    sQuote(update[i, 1L])), domain = NA) else if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: outfile <- if (keep_outputs) {
    paste0(update[i, 1L], ".out")
} else output
Browse[2]>
debug: output
Browse[2]>
debug: args <- c(args0, get_install_opts(update[i, 3L]), "-l", shQuote(update[i,
    2L]), getConfigureArgs(update[i, 3L]), getConfigureVars(update[i,
    3L]), update[i, 3L])
Browse[2]>
debug: status <- system2(cmd0, args, env = env, stdout = outfile, stderr = outfile)
Browse[2]>
debug: if (!quiet && keep_outputs) writeLines(readLines(outfile))
Browse[2]>
debug: if (status > 0L) warning(gettextf("installation of package %s had non-zero exit status",
    sQuote(update[i, 1L])), domain = NA) else if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: if (verbose) {
    cmd <- paste(c(cmd0, args), collapse = " ")
    message(sprintf("%d): succeeded '%s'", i, cmd), domain = NA)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: if (keep_outputs && (outdir != getwd())) file.copy(paste0(update[,
    1L], ".out"), outdir)
Browse[2]>
debug: if (!quiet && nonlocalrepos && !is.null(tmpd) && is.null(destdir)) cat("\n",
    gettextf("The downloaded source packages are in\n\t%s", sQuote(normalizePath(tmpd,
        mustWork = FALSE))), "\n", sep = "")
Browse[2]>
debug: cat("\n", gettextf("The downloaded source packages are in\n\t%s",
    sQuote(normalizePath(tmpd, mustWork = FALSE))), "\n", sep = "")
Browse[2]>

The downloaded source packages are in
        ‘/tmp/RtmpaUauPs/downloaded_packages’
debug: libs_used <- unique(update[, 2L])
Browse[2]>
debug: if (.Platform$OS.type == "unix" && .Library %in% libs_used) {
    message("Updating HTML index of packages in '.Library'")
    make.packages.html(.Library)
}
Browse[2]>
debug: invisible()
Browse[2]>
exiting from: install.packages("shiny")
>
>
```

### Problem

But I couldn't load `shiny` because it would be just downloaded, not unpacked to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library.

```
> library('shiny')
Error in library("shiny") : there is no package called ‘shiny’
> 
> installed.packages()
           Package      LibPath              Version   Priority
base       "base"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
boot       "boot"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "1.3-11"  "recommended"
class      "class"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-10"  "recommended"
cluster    "cluster"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "1.15.2"  "recommended"
codetools  "codetools"  "/usr/lib/R/library" "0.2-8"   "recommended"
compiler   "compiler"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
datasets   "datasets"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
foreign    "foreign"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "0.8-61"  "recommended"
graphics   "graphics"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
grDevices  "grDevices"  "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
grid       "grid"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
KernSmooth "KernSmooth" "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.23-12" "recommended"
lattice    "lattice"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "0.20-29" "recommended"
MASS       "MASS"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-33"  "recommended"
Matrix     "Matrix"     "/usr/lib/R/library" "1.1-3"   "recommended"
methods    "methods"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
mgcv       "mgcv"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "1.7-29"  "recommended"
nlme       "nlme"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1-117" "recommended"
nnet       "nnet"       "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-8"   "recommended"
parallel   "parallel"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
rpart      "rpart"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "4.1-8"   "recommended"
spatial    "spatial"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "7.3-7"   "recommended"
splines    "splines"    "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
stats      "stats"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
stats4     "stats4"     "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
survival   "survival"   "/usr/lib/R/library" "2.37-7"  "recommended"
tcltk      "tcltk"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
tools      "tools"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
utils      "utils"      "/usr/lib/R/library" "3.1.0"   "base"
           Depends
base       NA
boot       "R (>= 3.0.0), graphics, stats"
class      "R (>= 3.0.0), stats, utils"
cluster    "R (>= 2.12.0), stats, utils"
codetools  "R (>= 2.1)"
compiler   NA
datasets   NA
foreign    "R (>= 3.0.0), stats"
graphics   NA
grDevices  NA
grid       NA
KernSmooth "R (>= 2.5.0), stats"
lattice    "R (>= 2.15.1)"
MASS       "R (>= 3.0.0), grDevices, graphics, stats, utils"
Matrix     "R (>= 2.15.2), methods"
methods    NA
mgcv       "R (>= 2.14.0), nlme (>= 3.1-64)"
nlme       "graphics, stats, R (>= 3.0.0)"
nnet       "R (>= 2.14.0), stats, utils"
parallel   NA
rpart      "R (>= 2.15.0), graphics, stats, grDevices"
spatial    "R (>= 3.0.0), graphics, stats, utils"
splines    NA
stats      NA
stats4     NA
survival   "stats, utils, graphics, splines, R (>= 2.13.0)"
tcltk      NA
tools      NA
utils      NA
           Imports                                   LinkingTo
base       NA                                        NA
boot       NA                                        NA
class      "MASS"                                    NA
cluster    "graphics, grDevices"                     NA
codetools  NA                                        NA
compiler   NA                                        NA
datasets   NA                                        NA
foreign    "methods, utils"                          NA
graphics   "grDevices"                               NA
grDevices  NA                                        NA
grid       "grDevices"                               NA
KernSmooth NA                                        NA
lattice    "grid, grDevices, graphics, stats, utils" NA
MASS       NA                                        NA
Matrix     "graphics, grid, stats, utils, lattice"   NA
methods    "utils"                                   NA
mgcv       "methods, stats, graphics, Matrix"        NA
nlme       "lattice"                                 NA
nnet       NA                                        NA
parallel   "tools"                                   NA
rpart      NA                                        NA
spatial    NA                                        NA
splines    "graphics, stats"                         NA
stats      NA                                        NA
stats4     "graphics, methods, stats"                NA
survival   NA                                        NA
tcltk      "utils"                                   NA
tools      NA                                        NA
utils      NA                                        NA
           Suggests
base       NA
boot       "MASS, survival"
class      NA
cluster    "MASS"
codetools  NA
compiler   NA
datasets   NA
foreign    NA
graphics   NA
grDevices  NA
grid       "lattice"
KernSmooth "MASS"
lattice    "KernSmooth, MASS"
MASS       "lattice, nlme, nnet, survival"
Matrix     "expm, MASS"
methods    NA
mgcv       "splines, parallel"
nlme       "Hmisc, MASS"
nnet       "MASS"
parallel   NA
rpart      "survival"
spatial    "MASS"
splines    NA
stats      NA
stats4     NA
survival   NA
tcltk      NA
tools      NA
utils      NA
           Enhances                                License
base       NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
boot       NA                                      "Unlimited"
class      NA                                      "GPL-2 | GPL-3"
cluster    NA                                      "GPL (>= 2)"
codetools  NA                                      "GPL"
compiler   NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
datasets   NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
foreign    NA                                      "GPL (>= 2)"
graphics   NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
grDevices  NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
grid       NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
KernSmooth NA                                      "Unlimited"
lattice    "chron"                                 "GPL (>= 2)"
MASS       NA                                      "GPL-2 | GPL-3"
Matrix     "MatrixModels, graph, SparseM, sfsmisc" "GPL (>= 2)"
methods    NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
mgcv       NA                                      "GPL (>= 2)"
nlme       NA                                      "GPL (>= 2)"
nnet       NA                                      "GPL-2 | GPL-3"
parallel   "snow, nws, Rmpi"                       "Part of R 3.1.0"
rpart      NA                                      "GPL-2 | GPL-3"
spatial    NA                                      "GPL-2 | GPL-3"
splines    NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
stats      NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
stats4     NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
survival   NA                                      "LGPL (>= 2)"
tcltk      NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
tools      NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
utils      NA                                      "Part of R 3.1.0"
           License_is_FOSS License_restricts_use OS_type MD5sum
base       NA              NA                    NA      NA
boot       NA              NA                    NA      NA
class      NA              NA                    NA      NA
cluster    NA              NA                    NA      NA
codetools  NA              NA                    NA      NA
compiler   NA              NA                    NA      NA
datasets   NA              NA                    NA      NA
foreign    NA              NA                    NA      NA
graphics   NA              NA                    NA      NA
grDevices  NA              NA                    NA      NA
grid       NA              NA                    NA      NA
KernSmooth NA              NA                    NA      NA
lattice    NA              NA                    NA      NA
MASS       NA              NA                    NA      NA
Matrix     NA              NA                    NA      NA
methods    NA              NA                    NA      NA
mgcv       NA              NA                    NA      NA
nlme       NA              NA                    NA      NA
nnet       NA              NA                    NA      NA
parallel   NA              NA                    NA      NA
rpart      NA              NA                    NA      NA
spatial    NA              NA                    NA      NA
splines    NA              NA                    NA      NA
stats      NA              NA                    NA      NA
stats4     NA              NA                    NA      NA
survival   NA              NA                    NA      NA
tcltk      NA              NA                    NA      NA
tools      NA              NA                    NA      NA
utils      NA              NA                    NA      NA
           NeedsCompilation Built
base       NA               "3.1.0"
boot       "no"             "3.0.3"
class      "yes"            "3.0.3"
cluster    "yes"            "3.1.0"
codetools  NA               "3.0.3"
compiler   NA               "3.1.0"
datasets   NA               "3.1.0"
foreign    "yes"            "3.0.3"
graphics   NA               "3.1.0"
grDevices  NA               "3.1.0"
grid       NA               "3.1.0"
KernSmooth "yes"            "3.0.3"
lattice    "yes"            "3.1.0"
MASS       "yes"            "3.1.0"
Matrix     "yes"            "3.1.0"
methods    NA               "3.1.0"
mgcv       "yes"            "3.1.0"
nlme       "yes"            "3.1.0"
nnet       "yes"            "3.1.0"
parallel   NA               "3.1.0"
rpart      "yes"            "3.0.3"
spatial    "yes"            "3.0.3"
splines    NA               "3.1.0"
stats      NA               "3.1.0"
stats4     NA               "3.1.0"
survival   "yes"            "3.0.2"
tcltk      NA               "3.1.0"
tools      NA               "3.1.0"
utils      NA               "3.1.0"
```

How do I unpack these packages?

### My environment

```
# dpkg -l | grep r-base
ii  libgcr-base-3-1:amd64            3.10.1-1                      amd64        Library for Crypto related tasks
ii  r-base                           3.1.0-1trusty0                all          GNU R statistical computation and graphics system
ii  r-base-core                      3.1.0-1trusty0                amd64        GNU R core of statistical computation and graphics system
ii  r-base-dev                       3.1.0-1trusty0                all          GNU R installation of auxiliary GNU R packages
ii  r-base-html                      3.1.0-1trusty0                all          GNU R html docs for statistical computing system functions

# cat /etc/R/Renviron
### etc/Renviron.  Generated from Renviron.in by configure.
###
### ${R_HOME}/etc/Renviron
###
### Record R system environment variables.

R_PLATFORM=${R_PLATFORM-'x86_64-pc-linux-gnu'}
## Default printer paper size: first record if user set R_PAPERSIZE
R_PAPERSIZE_USER=${R_PAPERSIZE-'letter'}
R_PAPERSIZE=${R_PAPERSIZE-'letter'}
## Default print command
R_PRINTCMD=${R_PRINTCMD-'/usr/bin/lpr'}
# for Rd2pdf, reference manual
R_RD4PDF=${R_RD4PDF-'times,inconsolata,hyper'}
## used for options("texi2dvi")
R_TEXI2DVICMD=${R_TEXI2DVICMD-${TEXI2DVI-'/usr/bin/texi2dvi'}}
## used by INSTALL, untar() and installing grDevices
R_GZIPCMD=${R_GZIPCMD-'/bin/gzip'}
## Default zip/unzip commands
R_UNZIPCMD=${R_UNZIPCMD-'/usr/bin/unzip'}
R_ZIPCMD=${R_ZIPCMD-'/usr/bin/zip'}
R_BZIPCMD=${R_BZIPCMD-'/bin/bzip2'}
## Default browser
R_BROWSER=${R_BROWSER-'xdg-open'}
## Default editor
EDITOR=${EDITOR-${VISUAL-vi}}
## Default pager
PAGER=${PAGER-'/usr/bin/pager'}
## Default PDF viewer
R_PDFVIEWER=${R_PDFVIEWER-'/usr/bin/xdg-open'}
## Used by libtool
LN_S='ln -s'
MAKE=${MAKE-'make'}
## Prefer a POSIX-compliant sed on e.g. Solaris
SED=${SED-'/bin/sed'}
## Prefer a tar that can automagically read compressed archives
## Used in R CMD INSTALL for binary packages
TAR=${TAR-'/bin/tar'}

## System and compiler types.
R_SYSTEM_ABI='linux,gcc,gxx,gfortran,?'

R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/3.1'}
#R_LIBS_USER=${R_LIBS_USER-'~/Library/R/3.1/library'}

# edd Apr 2003  Allow local install in /usr/local, also add a directory for
#               Debian packaged CRAN packages, and finally the default dir
# edd Jul 2007  Now use R_LIBS_SITE, not R_LIBS
R_LIBS_SITE=${R_LIBS_SITE-'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/site-library:/usr/lib/R/library'}

### Local Variables: ***
### mode: sh ***
### sh-indentation: 2 ***
### End: ***
```

Comment: You probably need to add some swap space to your VPS/VM. Check if you have swap enabled `swapon -s`.

Comment: @jdharrison Do you think that `install.packages` should give an error here? Should this be reported as a bug/feature request?

Comment: I am not sure that monitoring what the OOM killer is doing is something that R should handle but it certainly is perplexing when the error occurs.

Comment: @jdharrison Maybe not monitoring the OOM killer, but the effects of it. The process should have a non-zero exit status. Of course the process itself cannot catch the SIGKILL but the parent should be able to see this. Or not?

Comment: I would be interested in the output of `install.packages` with `verbose = TRUE` set

Comment: also, `install.packages` is written mostly in R so you could run `debug(install.packages)`, then run the `install.packages('shiny')` command, and then step through it with `n`. On the first run, just keep pressing n and return until it exits. What is the last line that is run before it exits?

Comment: @scottkosty that sounds like a good idea. If someone can fire up an AWS micro instance and replicate the error it would be interesting to see what results.

Comment: Thank you for your support.
I've editted my post and added outputs. Do you seem to be able to identify the problem?

Comment: I noticed I had left out somthing. Making swap has resulted in successful installation. Thank you so much.

Comment: @YukiTakei is your output from `install.packages` with `verbose=TRUE` after or before you enabled swap? At the end, it says that `R CMD INSTALL` succeeded for all of the packages. If it is from before, then it is a mystery. Can you check the folder "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library" and see if the folders are indeed there and seem to look complete (e.g. not empty and have an "R" subfolder)

Comment: @scottkosty Sorry for the confusion. The output that I have added is got BEFORE I enabled swap. In spite of being output to the `X): succeeded '/usr/lib/R/bin/R CMD INSTALL -l ...`, there is no file in `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library`. After I have enabled swap, I made sure that everything is going well.

Comment: @YukiTakei Thanks for all of the info Yuki. This is a very high quality investigation on your part of what's going on. I appreciate all of the details you've given. This exact situation has been reported here: https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla3/show_bug.cgi?id=15796 so at least we know that it is a known bug. I will add a link to this report as a "me too" to show that it's not an uncommon situation.

Comment: @YukiTakei In case you are curious, there is a fix out at https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=15796  . Note that this fix is for the bug that there is no error.

Comment: @scottkosty Thank you for your mediation. I added a comment to bugzilla.